# Wordpress: Pretty permalink not working in ubuntu server

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, ubuntu-18.04

Server info:
http://prntscr.com/k7idex
CMS: Wordpress

URL is redirected to 404 in this format www.websitename.com/page-name/

Current URL: www.websitename.com/index.php/page-name/

I want to remove index.php in the URL.

Comment: First check mod_rewrite is installed or not . To install, type `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: Yes check for mod_rewrite install and then check for .htaccess rules needed for Wordpress are present and have the correct Apache readable permissions.

Comment: in virtual host change `AllowOverride All` for the directory